# How can I omit a class inheritance?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

I'm trying to find my way around. I have two classes, A and B, where B inherits from A.

There are also two overloaded functions for A and B, that act on them in two different ways.

Now call these functions from a class function like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;
struct B;

void f(A a);
void f(B b);

struct A {
  int i;
  A(): i(0) {};
  void thisf() { f(*this); }
};

struct B: public A {
  int j;
  B(): j(1) {};
  void thisf() { f(*this); }
};

void f(A a) { std::cout << a.i << std::endl; }
void f(B b) { std::cout << b.i << " " << b.j << std::endl; }

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;

  a.thisf();
  b.thisf();

  return 0;
}
```

My question is: **since A::thisf() and B::thisf() are the same (and will stay the same for more subclasses), is there a way how I can omit B::thisf() while still having the same functionality?**

The expected output should look like:

```
0
0 1
```

More detail why I try to do this: I want to provide some custom render functionality to different kinds of data without bloating the class with render logic and have a separate render class with some state variables. But I don't want to give up the possibility to write

```
 b.render()
```

in some situations. In my class definitions I want to spare every line I can.

I got the idea in this thread: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63912/visitor-pattern-vs-inheritance-for-rendering

Comment: I'm going to bounty 10 for finding the dupe ;-) ....

Comment: If you want to have the same implementation do not hide A::thisf() method in B by declatation of B::thisf() class declaration simply, then method will be the same.

Comment: @RobertWadowski but then I would get an output like "0\n0".

Comment: ok I understand question now in answer example will be pasted

Comment: @gm_fernandes thanks for the edit suggestions!

Comment: If you want thisf() to have different behavior between A and B, then you will need to have different implementations.  That said, you can A::thisf() call a virtual member function to do something, and just reimplement the "helper" function in the derived class without redoing the whole implementation of thisf().  Would need more details about the actual use case to offer guidance about how to use that sort of technique.

Comment: You seem to be looking for CRTP (or virtual).

Comment: @MarcGlisse CRTP seems to solve my problem! I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your proposed problem you claim the need for a method in `A` and `B` that is not polymorphic and yet exhibits different behaviour in the two classes (**linked by inheritance**) with the same signature.

In addition, the method defers to a free function found by ADL (**good!**).

So... my question to you is this. If you already have the guarantee of a free function called `f(A|B)`, why not simply document that as the interface?

If you insist on having `thisf()` you are causing yourself a problem because the inheritance relationship will cause `B`'s `thisf()` to be ambiguous with `A`'s. This can be solved with polymorphism (as per the other answer) but since you're rejecting that, you are are left with few options other than to eliminate the logically redundant `thisf()` altogether.

in any case, this code will do exactly as you want:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A;
struct B;

void f(A a);
void f(B b);

struct common_interface {
    virtual void thisf() = 0;
};

template<class Host, class Base>
struct common_interface_impl : Base {
    virtual void thisf() {
        f(static_cast<Host&>(*this));
    }
};

struct A : common_interface_impl<A, common_interface>
{
    int i;
    A(): i(0) {};
};

struct B: common_interface_impl <B, A>
{
    int j;
    B(): j(1) {};
};

void f(A a) { std::cout << a.i << std::endl; }
void f(B b) { std::cout << b.i << " " << b.j << std::endl; }

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    a.thisf();
    b.thisf();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! But what do you mean by "document that [`f(A|B)`] as the interface"?

Comment: `A::thisf()` is merely a proxy for `f(A)`. `B::thisf()` is a proxy for `f(B)`. Therefore if you know the type of A or B at the call site, it's sufficient to call `f()`. You only need a polymorphic `thisf()` if you don't know the actual type when the call takes place.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int i;
  A(): i(0) {};
  virtual ~A() {};
  virtual void thisf() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

struct B: public A {
  int j;
  B(): j(1) {};
  void thisf() { A::thisf(); std::cout << j << std::endl; }
};

void f( A* a )
{
   a->thisf();
}

int main() {
  A* a = new A();
  A* b = new B();

  f( a ); f( b );

  delete a; delete b;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not exactly what I am looking for: I try to achieve that the call of f() detects for every call "intelligently" if it gets a class A or B, do you know what I mean? But I get the feeling that this isn't possible like I hoped...

Comment: This is closest thing you want

Comment: Why the dynamic allocation all of a sudden? And what does the "virtual" do? And why the destructor for A?

Comment: this is called polimorphysm, depending on type under pointer apropriate method is called. virtual keyword creates vtable ( or called some like that ) table that holds all method with the same signature. ingheritting classes can reimplement functions. During invocation of method for pointer appropriate method will be called depending on type under pointer. More info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: Virtual destructor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors